# Corresponding command to `\mkbibemph` for normal font

Tags: fonts, biblatex

What is the corresponding command of `\mkbibemph` for the normal font? I want to change the italic font of the article-journal in a normal font. Some like `\DeclareFieldFormat[journal]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`.

Answer (score 3):

The normal font is the default. So to answer the question, *not* using anything like `mkbibemph` does not change from normal font to anything else.

In the following image red color was added to make the change more clear.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
```

would give just a normal looking result for the journal title.

[image: texsxNormalfontBib]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{{\color{red!60!black}#1}}
\begin{document}
Many scientific articles do not contain any stuff about Wombats,
one example was delivered by \textcite{bertram}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```